# Poincaré Bendixson Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the system $x' = 8x−2y−4x^3 −2xy^3$ and $y' = x + 4y − 2y^3 − 3x^2y$ has a limit cycle. I was given a hint to use the Lyapunov function $x^2 + 2y^2$. 
Now, I have $\dot V= 4x - 2x^4 + 4y^2 - 2y^4 - x^2y^3 -3x^2y^2$, but I'm not sure where to go from here. All of the examples I have seen simplify pretty easily into circles or ellipses.
I'm new to this theorem and still kind of confused by it, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Amzoti fixed it, thanks!